# Count number of individuals detected in one group or both

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame with individuals and which site they were detected.

```
ID      Location       
5994    Greshornish
5994    Snizort    
6017    Greshornish
6018    Greshornish
6020    Greshornish
6020    Snizort
6021    Greshornish
46507   Greshornish
46508   Snizort
46511   Greshornish
46512   Greshornish
46512   Snizort
```

I would like to count the number of individuals detected at one site or both. For example, in the table above I would get something like

```
Location      Count
Greshornish     5
Snizort         1 
Both            3
```

I can't figure out the best way to do this although I'm sure it's quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Location = ifelse(n() == 2, "Both", Location)) %>% 
  count(Location, name = "Count")

#   Location    Count
# 1 Both            3
# 2 Greshornish     5
# 3 Snizort         1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:)

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% group_by(Location) %>% tally() %>% rename(Count = n)
```